# Subseting the time from the date column

Tags: r

Hi All Thanks in advance

I Have a Data In Which The Date Column Includes The Time Also

example :

```
2019-03-27 03:45:17 PM 
2019-03-27 03:49:14 PM
2019-03-27 03:38:39 PM
```

I would like to delete only the time in the date column

I have tried the below.

```
rock1 <- gsub(rock$Created.On, pattern= "0:00:00",replacement="",fixed=T)
drrr <- as.character(as.Date(rock$Created.On, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The Expected result is

```
DATE
2019-03-01
2019-03-02
2019-02-03
```

Comment: Why the dates changed when the time got deleted?

Answer (score 1):

We can just do `as.Date`

```
df1$DATE <- as.Date(df1$DATE)
df1$DATE
#[1] "2019-03-27" "2019-03-27" "2019-03-27"
```

assuming that the dates shouldn't change as well

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DATE = c("2019-03-27 03:45:17 PM", "2019-03-27 03:49:14 PM", 
 "2019-03-27 03:38:39 PM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: Its Not Working

Comment: @ArunP  Based on the data given, it is working for me.  UPdated with the data used

Comment: Having Another issue akrun how to add a row after 14 rows, i need to add another new row

Comment: @ArunP  That is a different issue not connected with the question

Comment: Yes These is different, I have done a pivot and got the output also,But i cant get the sum of it ,i have tried these    library(tidyverse)

glimpse(rock)

blof <- rock %>% group_by(Lead.Stage) %>%
  count()%>%
  arrange(desc(n))

rock %>% filter(rock == "Personal.Email")%>%
  group_by(Personal.Email)
blof %>%
summarise(sum(blof$n))